# Assign/Unassign roles using discord.NET

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign and unassign roles using discord.net, I tried this:

```
if (message.Author is SocketGuildUser socketUser)
{
     SocketGuild socketGuild = socketUser.Guild;
     var user = socketGuild.GetUser(UserID);
     var role = socketGuild.GetRole(RoleID);
     user.RemoveRoleAsync(role);
}
```

Although it didn't remove the role. I used the same code with the addrole but changed the RemoveRoleAsync with AddRoleAsync

Comment: You’re not awaiting an asynchronous method

Comment: returns forbidden, is there a solution?

Comment: `async` wants to propagate all the way us the call stack, you can use `Wait` or `Result` but if you’re going to use `async` you’re better off going all the way and making  _everything_ async - if you ‘mix and match’ async and non-async code then weird and hard-to-debug things can (well, will) happen